# Revit to ifc schedule using autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative, ifc

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-revit.ifc.scheduler

I want to build same app, I have cloned it on local path.It is not working.Kindly help, or give another solution or give some idea.

I have tried Dynamo revit files stored in Bim 360.It takes too much time to open and close files in batch process.Make research and get Idea about forge .cloned project

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-revit.ifc.scheduler

But not working.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the "It is not working"? Any error message shows up in the conversion history?

Comment: BTW, this sample uses this approach https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/export-ifc-rvt-using-model-derivative-api, not via Revit API.

Comment: It is stucked on paid nmp packages

Comment: There is no paid npm package as I know. Do you mean paid Model Derivative API?

Comment: Can you provide a video of the set up from clone this app

Comment: Here you go: https://youtu.be/0lrctnbBbPY

Comment: Thank you for your video , and efforts behind it☺️